# Which benefits do Twists of elliptic curves bring?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I understand that an elliptic curve $E$ over a field $K$ has an associated twist, that is another elliptic curve which is isomorphic to $E$ over an algebraic closure of $K$.

Which cryptographic benefits do twists of elliptic curves bring?

Comment: [Twisted curves in protocol](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/16539/18298) [Understanding Twist Security with respect to short Weierstrass curves](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/19877/18298) [What is the difference between regular and "twisted" ECC curves?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/42427/18298)

Comment: Well, although they are isomorphic in the closure, the closure is not a good field for the performance, so we work on the base field. In this case, the twist needs to have large subgroups to be secure against the [twist attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=twist+attack)

Comment: This may be hard for people to understand if they do not understand the maths behind elliptic curves. Can we conclude that publishing a twisted version of a curve that this is because it indicates what kind of attacks can be performed against schemes that use the particular curve? Most answers do describe the math well, but they fall short of giving a comprehensive answer on how twisted curves are *used*, if at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short answer;

We want fast and secure arithmetic and sometimes the twist of a curve may produce secure and faster arithmetic;

- EdDSA : Ed25519 : twisted Edwards curve :

  [High-speed high-security signatures - 2011](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/ed25519-20110926.pdf) Daniel J. Bernstein, Niels Duif, Tanja Lange, Peter Schwabe, and Bo-Yin Yang

  - Fast

    - fast single-signature verification
    - Even faster batch verification.
    - Very fast signing
    - Fast key generation
  - Secure

    - No secret branch conditions
    - No secret array indices
    - Uses a twisted Edwards curve that is birationally equivalent to the curve Curve25519 implied ECDLP is equivalent to Curve25519

---

From [rfc8032 : Edwards-Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (EdDSA)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8032)

> The Edwards-curve Digital Signature Algorithm (EdDSA) is a variant of
> Schnorr's signature system with (**possibly twisted**) Edwards curves.

So, whenever there is a benefit, the twist can be used.

---

**A note on the birationally equivalence**

Birationally equivalence is the relaxation of the isomorphism where we want some of the points not mapped with the forward and backward birational maps.

Now, we know that Discrete Logarithms are [random self-reducibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_self-reducibility). What this tells us; if we can solve Dlog in one base then we can solve any base. (Solve for base $G$ the find $P = [a]G$ for base $P$ and see $S = [t]P = [ta]G$..)

By using this and birationally equivalence we can argue that if Dlog hard in Curve25519 then DLog is hard in the twisted Edwards curve. too. If easy then it is easy there too. Just map the points and solve them. If the points are not mappable then use some other as a base use
random self-reducibility.

Comment: Could be enhanced by indicating if using the twisted curve would create fully compatible results.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes do you mean the points are not mapped due to birationally equivalence? they are finite, however, the main point of birational equivalence is `Our recommended curve for EdDSA is a twisted Edwards
curve birationally equivalent to the curve Curve25519 from [12]. Any efficiently
computable birational equivalence preserves ECDLP difficulty, so the well-known
difficulty of computing ECDLP for Curve25519 immediately implies the difficulty
of computing ECDLP for our curve.` Not really mapping the points... Otherwise we need to consider the to exclude the non-mapping points!

Comment: @kelalaka how do twists bring faster arithmetic in comparison with protocols that don't use them (asking because unified addition is also available for Edward curves that are not twisted)?

Comment: There is no magic but deep study there. When you get the quadratic twist, you need to see what you get get this from this twist. This requires looking from the coordinate systems to protocols that can benefit from this. For study, you can generate a random Edward's curve ( possibly large ) and see what this twist can be useful or not.